# Import html to ipython notebook file

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way how to import piece of html code from html file to ipynb file?

I would like to have one html file, what will render in multiple ipynb files.

Only information what I found about ipynb imports is:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb

And it does not make it clearer for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could simply use the HTML object supplied by IPython like

```py
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(filename='myhtml.html')
```

If you don't want the result being an output but rather display it, use the `display` method (`from IPython.display import display`.

Moreover, you could use an IFrame in the same manner.