# How to integrate plotly plots from other jupyter notebooks into a new notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, jupyter

Currently I have several jupyter notebooks where I have different plots. I can export each notebook as html and it works fine. What I want is to create a summary notebook with all important plots from different notebooks. Is this possible, if yes how?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export each figure (instead of the entire notebook) using the `.write_html` function if you haven't already done this. Something like:

From notebook #1:

```
fig.write_html(/figures/fig1.html)
```

...
From notebook #N:

```
fig.write_html(/figures/figN.html)
```

Then in a new notebook, you can load all of your Plotly figures saved as htmls based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462893/import-html-to-ipython-notebook-file).

Something like the following:

New notebook:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

# in a new cell:
HTML(filename='fig1.html')

#...

#...final cell:
HTML(filename='figN.html')
```

Comment: Thanks, saving the graph works. But in the new notebook it doesn't show up. Do I need some html layout where I have to embed the figure? Just using HTML(filename='fig1.html') shows an empty white space and no graph. When I click the html file it opens fine in the browser and shows me the graph.

Comment: I checked it again, with `IFrame(src='./fig.html', width=700, height=600)` it works fine and is embeded. Thank you very much.